# Prestashop category items decreasing in size as you scroll down the page on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Recently I've encountered a problem with my Prestashop store (ver 1.7.7.1). I changed the default theme with a new one and on a desktop everything seems fine.
A customer brought to my attention that while browsing the store from his phone, the items in any of the categories decrease in size as he's scrolling down the page.
Furthermore, when I click on a product and the product page opens, the first image is bigger than the display (I'm using combinations because I have a product with different colors) and also the default combination cover image is the wrong one. If I click on the second image and then back on the first one everything looks ok.
I tried modyfing the theme's css with no luck.
I'm guessing that is a javascript problem but I'm not a coder so this problem is above my head.
The site in question is [gentidebarbati.ro](https://gentidebarbati.ro)
I would really appreciate it if you could take a look and maybe figure out where the problem is coming from.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a javascript problem ..
It seems that one html element is not closed on your product listing page.

Check the 'catalog/_partials/miniatures/product.tpl' and the   'catalog/_partials/products.tpl' files.

And for solving the product page image bug, add this code to the custom.css

```
body#product .slick-initialized .slick-slide img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

}

Comment: I found the html element that wasn't closed and the solution worked like a charm.
I added the code to custom.css but nothing happens.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It worked. I didn't clear the browser's cache. 
Thank you so so much!

Comment: I found another bug :D
On some products that have combinations, when I click on a product, the default product thumbnail is not the default combination image.
If I click on the secondary image and then back on the first one, the right default image appears.